# How to visually display a b-tree in java?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, graph, b-tree

I'm implementing a B-Tree, and would like to display it in a simple UI (or text output) for debugging. What library would you recommend to do this as quickly as possible?

This is just meant as a debugging tool, it should be as simple as possible - I don't want to waste time learning a complicated UI framework just for this. If you know of something that will print it to STDOUT, that's fine as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is easy to use

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using an applet, here is an example: http://slady.net/java/bt/view.php

This one has got the source code also: http://sky.fit.qut.edu.au/~maire/baobab/baobab.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you're wasting your time with the idea of using a visual representation for debugging. Instead, you should have a method that checks the entire tree for correctness (and describes the context of errors very verbosely).

Then, during testing, call that method after every step that modifies the tree's structure. That way, it should be relatively easy to pinpoint bugs - and probably faster than looking through a visual representation as well.

Comment: I'll take your tip and skip it, but still I'm accepting @Enqirue's answer. Your answer is more fitting as a comment.